# put element on bottom of parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dynamic list of divs in a parent div. The only class I know, is one div, which should be positioned at the bottom of the container. How can I do this?

Problem:

```
<div>
 <div class="i-want-to-be-the-last-element"></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>

<div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="i-want-to-be-the-last-element"></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>

<div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="i-want-to-be-the-last-element"></div>
</div>
```

Solution should like like this:

```
<div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="i-want-to-be-the-last-element"></div>
</div>

<div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="i-want-to-be-the-last-element"></div>
</div>

<div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="i-want-to-be-the-last-element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And where is your php code?

Comment: You need to physically move that class within the DOM, so it's last? Or you just want it to be visually rendered at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements and then append theme to their parent container using `.appendTo()` or `.append()`:

```
$('.i-want-to-be-the-last-element').each(function(){
     $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/722xLpuq/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$this = $(".i-want-to-be-the-last-element").parent();
var content = $(".i-want-to-be-the-last-element").detach();
$this.append(content);
```